# Parallel and Sequential execution of test cases in single test suite in ReadyAPI project

Tags: ready-api

I have a scenario in which I have 3 test cases(Warm Up, Store Entities, Fetch  Entities) in 1 test suite(Server warm up request). In this, First I have to run **Warm Up** request and then **Store Entities, Fetch  Entities** both in parallel.

Please help and let me know how I can do it.

Please see the attached image for the reference.

Thank you in advance for your help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByuRn.png)

Comment: Did you try the documentation? https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/functional/running/multiple-items/suites.html

Comment: Yes, I have tried/read this but this is saying to run either parallel or sequential. However my requirement is to run few test case in parallel and few test case in sequential of a test suite.

Answer (score 0):

In your test suite:

1. Disable your Warm up.
2. Set the test suite test run mode to parallel.
3. Create a Test Suite setup script that contains:
   `testSuite.getTestCaseByName("Warm Up") .run((com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap)context, false)`

There is some additional detail on [my blog](https://siking.wordpress.com/2013/11/01/testing-concurrency-with-soapui/).